# How do you read this, "to staff a 100 bed"?

Tags: pronunciation, reading-aloud

> The health provider will get $20 million from the Abbott Government to staff **a 100** bed hospital in Sierra Leone. ([here](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/481) is the audio) (from Aussie ABC)

I don’t hear clearly how the presenter is saying this number, 100. ‘a-hundred’ or ‘hundred’. I hear the latter. But the presenter might be saying ‘to staffa a-hundred,’ not ‘to staff a hundred.’ How do you read the number, 100? ‘A-hundred’ or ‘hundred’? If it was 200, would you read ‘to staff a two-hundred’?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*... to staff a 100-bed hospital ...*

This could be said either as "a one-hundred-bed hospital" or more simply, "a hundred-bed hospital". The second was what the announcer in your clip said.

We can have a 200-bed hospital, "a two-hundred-bed hospital". Indeed, we can use any number there. The 'a' is necessary, The 'one' before numbers beginning with *one hundred/thousand* (*100, 110, 175, 1,000*, etc) is optional.

Comment: To use and articulate `a **one-hundred-bed hospital**` is to emphasize.

Answer (score 2):

To use and articulate `a one-hundred-bed hospital` is to emphasize, while saying `a hundred` is very passive.

Apparently this `hundred-bed` hospital is not to big of a deal.  It nearly sounds like the presenter is indicating some kind of experiment; an experiment funded by Abbott.

### EMPHASIS EXAMPLE

> Abbott gave ONE Hundred Million Dollars to charity!  That is quite a lot of money!

### PASSIVE EXAMPLE

> Abbott gave a hundred million dollars to charity.  He couldn't think of anything else to spend it on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either "a one-hundred" or "a hundred". I am not aware of any prescribed grammar in this circumstance. Maybe because it has become an all too familiar usage.

But, just to be analytical: "a—used as a function word before singular nouns when the referent is unspecified  and before number collectives and some numbers "

Technically, 'a' in this circumstance is an indefinite article (singular). Which means it can be any 'hundred', not a specific 'hundred.'

Where these examples refer to a specific hundred: 
1.) This hundred bed hospital.
2.) That hundred bed hospital.
3.) Your hundred bed hospital.

'One-hundred bed hospital' itself does not refer to a specific or non-specific one-hundred bed hospital. It only really creates an lexicon image.

One is not required before hundred because in this case (and most all cases) hundred is a noun. Just the same as any other noun, it is understood already as '1' singular. (Cat or One Cat, bed or one bed)